# How to fetch object in object data from API in React-Native

Tags: api, react-native

I need to get the data from the object room:{...}, but I'm stuck into just log the whole data from the API in the console. I need some help..............................................................

That's my code for now:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         currentDate: new Date(),
         markedDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
         isLoading: true,
         room: []
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
         fetch("https://URL/api/schedule?resolve[]=room", {method: "GET"})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
           this.setState({room: responseJson});
           console.log(responseJson);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const today = this.state.currentDate;
        const month = moment(today).format("MMMM");
        const date = moment(today).format("D")
        const day = moment(today).format("dddd");

       

        return (...)
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "id": 190,
    "employee_id": 6,
    "room_id": 28,
    "type_of_cleaning": "D",
    "date": "2020-10-05",
    "room": {
        "data": {
            "id": 28,
            "customer_id": 5,
            "room_type_id": 19,
            "room_inventory_template_id": 8,
            "name": "154",
            "floor": 3
        }
    },
    "room-room_type": {
        "data": {
            "id": 19,
            "customer_id": 5,
            "name": "room_types_4451C9D4CD"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to display the room 'name' and 'floor'.

Comment: const roomName = this.state.room?.data?.name AND
const roomFloor = this.state.room?.data?.floor

Answer (score 0):

set initialstate of room to null

```js
   this.state = {
         currentDate: new Date(),
         markedDate: moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
         isLoading: true,
         room: null
        };
```

```js
let roomName = ''
let roomFloor = '
if (this.state.room) {
  roomName = this.state.room.data.name
  roomFloor = this.state.room.data.floor
  }
```

Comment: How can I display them

Comment: I try with <Text>{roomName}</Text>

Comment: let roomName = ''
        let roomFloor = 0
        if (this.state.room) {
            roomName = this.state.room.room.data.name
            roomFloor = this.state.room.room.data.floor
        }

Comment: change to this.state.room.room.data.floor and this.state.room.room.data.name

Comment: Undefined is not an object

Comment: For this.state.room.room.data

Answer (score 0):

Your `room` state object contain the same data as your JSON.

You could access the by using
name : `this.state.room.room.data.name`
floor: `this.state.room.room.data.floor`

then you can display it as
`<Text>{this.state.room.room.data.name}</Text>` and
`<Text>{this.state.room.room.data.floor}</Text>`

make sure u have the same structure of data in your state room object when accessing the data or it will cause error

Comment: Undefined is not an object (evaluating _.this.state.room) https://snack.expo.io/mmeK25yNU

Comment: I checked out the example you provided. Obviously it's not gonna work like that. As you have `setState` for your `room` object with responseJson, `this.state.room` will contain exactly the same JSONObject. So you just have to make sure that room is not undefined or null, then you can access the value by the code given above. I suggest than you can predefined the room state as null, then do a render logic check to avoid any further error